# CURL Fileupload REST API

Tags: php, curl

I am Trying to Call File Upload REST API Using Curl but it returns blank screen i dont know whats going wrong.
File Upload API Returns File Name if Success.
same thing i am able to call fule upload rest api using postman tool.

**Error:**

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Sequence contains no matching element",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": " at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)\r\n at PharmaRackv2.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UploadController.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
try {
            $file = "D:\xampp\htdocs\api.pharmarack.com\distributors\11380\08122017123602.zip";
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "http://test.com/api/upload",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'attachment' => curl_file_create($file),
            ),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "cache-control: no-cache",
                    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
                    "distributorcode: 1HUBH",
                    "foldername: 1HUBH"
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            if ($err) {
                echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

**POSTMAN CALL**
It is working fine. File Upload API Returns File Name if Success.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `DistributorCode` and `FolderName` are case sensitive, that is why you are getting error in your curl. fix that Like:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
    "DistributorCode: 1HUBH",
    "FolderName: 1HUBH"
),
```

**Edit:** The problem is that with `multipart/form-data`, you need to send the data via boundries, you can't send it like `file=abc.php`, like usual post param.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://ragabh.com/api/upload",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------FormData\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"E:\\c5-500x500.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------FormData--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----FormData",
    "DistributorCode: 1HUBH",
    "FolderName: 1HUBH",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```